# google-maps-services embed dependency in aem

Tags: google-maps-api-3, osgi, aem, bnd, bndtools

I want to use google-maps-services in my aem project inorder to get the user location by using geocodingApi.I have tried adding dependency in pom, but its not worked resulted com.google.maps -- Cannot be resolved, com.google.maps.model -- Cannot be resolved.

Further, I tried adding embed dependencies like below and the build was success, but I'm not seeing the google-maps bundle in felix console.

```
<groupId>biz.aQute.bnd</groupId>
<artifactId>bnd-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
<execution>
<configuration>
<bnd>
<![CDATA[
Import-Package: javax.annotation;version=0.0.0, javax.net.*;version=0.0.0, \
                    com.day.cq.search;version="[1.3.0,2)", \
                    com.day.cq.wcm.api;version="[1.27.0,2)", \
                    org.apache.commons. lang3;version="[3.9.0,4)", \
                    org.apache.sling.api.resource;version="[2.11.1,3)", \
                    Export-Package:      com.google.maps.*,io.opencensus.tags,
io.opencensus.stats,com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch,
okhttp3.Interceptor.*,okio.* , \
                    Embed-Dependency: google-maps-services,okhttp,
okio,opencensus-api,appengine-api-1.0-sdk

                                    ]]>
        </bnd>
    </configuration>
  </execution>
```

Answer (score 0):

Embedding in bnd-maven-plugin can be achieved a bit differently. You should use "includeresource" instead "Embed-Dependency" which was used in maven bundle plugin

For example

```
-includeresource: \
lib/feign-core.jar=feign-core-*.jar;lib:=true,\
lib/feign-okhttp.jar=feign-okhttp-*.jar;lib:=true,\
lib/feign-jackson.jar=feign-jackson-*.jar;lib:=true,\
```